# Multi-colored UILabel text

Tags: iphone, uilabel

Is is possible to create multi-colored text within a UILabel?  I.e, if my text was:

"The quick brown fox"

have the q and b in blue with the rest of the text in black?

I get the feeling I'd have to use a UIWebView and render the text in HTML to accomplish this.  Thoughts?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel

Comment: Hello I amd Getting This Error*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xdbb5cc'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that you need to use a UIWebView.  Alternatively, you can draw the text yourself into a custom view, but that would probably be a lot more difficult to implement.

If you are going to draw it yourself, you'll want to use the drawing methods in [NSString UIKit Additions](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/drawAtPoint:withFont:) along with the [-[UIColor set]](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIColor/set) method etc.

Answer (score 1):

Rendering the text using HTML in a UIWebView is the recommended method from apple.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to concatenate an array of UILabels each with their own individual settings (such as text colour). In your case the label would be broken into labels as [The ][q][uick ][b][rown fox].

Comment: @titaniumdecoy: Can you expand on that?

Answer (score 0):

`CoreText` can be successfully used in many applications.

Answer (score 0):

We can do it using CoreText  Framework,You can study further more using this link [CoreText Tutorial for iOS](http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.in/2011/06/coretext-tutorial-for-ios-part-1.html)