# iPhone, change color to each letter

Tags: iphone, sdk

It is possible to change a NSString color by letter?

For example, if you have `NSString *A=@"ASDFGH";`

show in UILabel ASD with red and FGH with blue.

And another question..
If I have a NSString, can I access the letter I want?
For example, in `NSString *A=@"ASDFGH";` how can I know what is the second letter which is S, or the third, which is D?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976799/multi-colored-uilabel-text) question out.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976799/multi-colored-uilabel-text

Answer (score 0):

for your second question you can use these three methods of NSString

```
 – substringFromIndex:
 – substringWithRange:
 – substringToIndex:
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to either create separate UILabels for each group of characters in the string , use [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637631/how-do-i-display-a-nsattributedstring-on-an-iphone)), or you can just use CoreGraphics to render each group in a different color. The latter is probably the most efficient but also the most complex.

2) Use -[NSString characterAtIndex:] like so:

```
NSString *string = @"ASDFGH";
unichar char = [string characterAtIndex:1]; //the second letter
if (char == 'S') {
  //do something
}
```